# Getting other language values synchronously in ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate to offer a website in different languages. The part that I am currently working on is the Angular Routes. As I want to offer even the routes in different languages, I need to access my translations pretty early in runtime.
To accomplish that, I preload my default language translation with an appInitializerFactory and that works. I am able to access translations of the selected language via .instant() to apply to my routes.

My problem is that I am not able to preload or use any other translations than my default one, because getTranslation() is working asynchronously and they don't seem to be loaded in time.

I have been looking for already implemented solutions like ngx-translate-routes and ngx-translate-router, but they are either not stable enough or not being updated regularly.

**My Code: (app-routing.module.ts)**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {},
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: () => {
        let routes: Routes = [];

        routes.push(
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
        );

        const translate = AppInjector.get(TranslateService);
        const langs = translate.getLangs();

        langs.forEach(function(lang) {

          translate.getTranslation(lang).forEach(function (transl) {

            routes.push(

              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['home']['path_name'], component: LandingComponent, title: transl['routes']['home']['title']},
              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['products']['path_name'], component: ProductsComponent, title: transl['routes']['products']['title']},
              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['about_us']['path_name'], component: AboutUsComponent, title: transl['routes']['about_us']['title']},
              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['contact']['path_name'], component: ContactComponent, title: transl['routes']['contact']['title']},
              {path:lang + '/' + transl['routes']['support']['path_name'], component: SupportComponent, title: transl['routes']['support']['title']},

              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['legal_notice']['path_name'], component: LegalNoticeComponent, title: transl['routes']['legal_notice']['title']},
              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['privacy']['path_name'], component: PrivacyComponent, title: transl['routes']['privacy']['title']},
              {path: lang + '/' + transl['routes']['gtc']['path_name'], component: GtcComponent, title: transl['routes']['gtc']['title']},

              {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, title: transl['routes']['page_not_found']['title']}
            );

            console.log(routes);

          });

        });
        return [
            ...routes
          ];

      },
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

**What I've tried**

- Making the useFactory async and awaiting the forEach
- Returning the routes object in a .then()
- Leaving the home route untranslated and pushing it together with the redirect path to be synchronous

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the `Router` class, you can update your config at any time of your lifecycle app.

You don't need to do it in a factory provider.

[Here is the related documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetConfig)

So simply do your thing in AppModule or AppComponent, while preventing the user from navigating (for instance, not showing the routerLinks with a ngIf), and when it's loaded, just show it.

Comment: My problem with your solution is, that when a user wants to access a path directly, it throws an error because the route is not existant yet.

Comment: That's why I said to prevent it ...

Comment: I understood that, but if a user accesses a link directly, for example from another page, the error gets thrown anyways and I don't know of a way on how to prevent that.

Comment: That's what "preventing" meant. Use either an app initializer or a CanActivate guard to do that.